# got C2758 error for my third party call

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-constructor

I declared my class as follows in my "first.h" :

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass ( cv::Mat& _model ) : tmpM ( _model )
    {
    };
private:
cv::Mat& tmpM;
}
```

then in "first.cpp", I used it like this:

```
MyClass::tmpM ( cv::Mat& _model )
{
    ...
}
```

Then I included this "first.h" in my "second.h", and include this "second.h" in my "third.h", then in my "third.cpp" I tried to do this:

```
cv::Mat testMat ( height, width, CV_8UC3 );
tmpM myM ( testMat );
```

Then I got errors saying:

> > 'MyClass::tmpM': not a function
> >
> > error C2512: 'MyClass': no appropriate default constructor available
> >
> > IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "cv::Mat& MyClass::tmpM"
> >
> > IntelliSense: explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)

Before you ask, I have to say I indeed searched and asked about this, but still couldn't solve it. I am a learner, so could someone help me out of this? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you got are quite explicit.

```
'MyClass::tmpM': not a function
```

Means that `tmpM` is not a function and it comes from the declaration

```
MyClass::tmpM ( cv::Mat& _model ) {
    ...
}
```

I think you are confused and wanted to declare the constructor, in which case you should have written in your header file (i added a default constructor)

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass ( cv::Mat& _model );
private:
    MyClass(); // Private default constructor
    cv::Mat& tmpM;
}
```

And then in your cpp file

```
MyClass::MyClass( cv::Mat& _model ) {
    // Do things
}
```

This will solve your second error message:

```
error C2512: 'MyClass': no appropriate default constructor available
```

Your third file is also problematic because in line

```
tmpM myM ( testMat );
```

`tmpM` is not a type. I think you meant

```
MyClass myM( testMat );
```

and that's what the two last errors are telling you.

Comment: I did it like you said, then it gives out error saying "function 'MyClass::MyClass' (cv::Mat& _model)' already has a body, plus still the "C2512" error.

Comment: What did you want tyo do when you declared `MyClass::tmpM ( cv::Mat& _model ) {}` ? If you just wanted a constructor, you can indeed erase it because a constructor is already declared when you do `MyClass ( cv::Mat& _model ) : tmpM ( _model )
    {
    };`

Comment: I declared it in my "first.cpp" file to do some work for the input model.

Comment: But was that meant to be a function? A constructor? What do you do inside it?

Comment: It is a constructor, sorry for my error. But if I delete the "MyClass(cv::Mat& _model) : tmpM (_model){}", and write it as "MyClass::tmp(cv::Mat& _model), it says it needs a default constructor.

Comment: You can just add it and leave it empty: `MyClass() {}`. If you don't want it to be called, make it `private`.

Comment: just as I said, it gives out an error saying it already has a body.

Comment: I updated my answer, is that clearer to you? about the default constructor `MyClass()`

Comment: it says "error C2248: cannot access private member declared in 'MyClass'".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18360/discussion-between-alestanis-and-ederman)

Answer (score 1):

You declared this:

```
cv::Mat& tmpM;
```

and redeclared it thusly:

```
MyClass::tmpM ( cv::Mat& _model )
```

In the first, you declare on object. In the second you declare a function.

Fix one or the other so that they match.